# Add custom classes in Quill

Tags: javascript, quill

So I readed through the Docs and stuff but simply didnt find a simpel example that I can build up on. I have for example the `<blockquote>` Tag, now i simpyl wanna set a default in the Editor that every blockquote has a specific class.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I have a similar use case for lists. I need to add a class to every list tag dependent on their level in the list (eg. first level and ql-indent-1 level). Please let me know when you find something. Thanks.

Comment: @Badgy did you find out any solution for this ? Please let me know if you find something. Thanks